# Is it possible to ask for a minimal depth for quotation and swap?

Tags: 0x

I'm using 0x. The documentation is great, but a field `depth` looks missing. It's probably not implemented, but I still ask the question.

Suppose I want a very quick quotation for `WETH -> USDT`

I think that having calculating all routes `WETH -> USDC -> USDT, WETH -> DAI -> USDT`, etc are way longer than just direct routes `WETH -> USDT`, so I would like to express this in the api such as :

```
https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=USDT&sellToken=WETH&sellAmount=100000000&depth=1
```

It could also reduce the error/revert rate. Is it something possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you asking is not possible as the 0x API tries always to find the best price, what is a workardound is you manually exclude the sources you don't want and just use for instance Uniswap, as you can see on the excludedSources on  https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote#request. I don't find this feasible.

Recent update on 0x API is with Mev protection so it should already offer a quote with the minimal reverts possible.